# Как получить событие мыши внутри процедуры?

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic

Подскажите как можно определить событие мыши внутри процедуры?

```
    Private Sub NavItem_Event(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) _
        Handles _
        Label2.MouseEnter, Label2.MouseLeave, Label2.Click,
        Label3.MouseEnter, Label3.MouseLeave, Label3.Click

    End Sub
```

Я вижу это примерно так:

```
Select Case e.MouseEvent
    Case : "MouseEnter"
    sender.someProperty = newValue

    Case : "MouseLeave"
    sender.someProperty = prevValue
End Select
```

Хочу так сказать внутри одной процедуры убить стадо зайцев.

UPD:

Возможно какая то либа из user32.dll станет в помощь?

Comment: у вас должен быть один обработчик-процедура, и его надо подключить  к двум разным событиям: MouseEnter и MouseLeave

Comment: Это я в курсе, просто интересует возможно ли организовать сие действие. Только изучаю язык и по сути техническая документация мне не скажет в чем я прав а в чем нет. Возможно какая то либа из  user32.dll станет в помощь и т.п.